# All norm in a finite dimensional topological space are equivalent

Tags: normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

> **Definition**
>
> If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space then we say that the norm $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ are equivalent if and only if there exist two positive constant $m$ and $M$ such that
> $$
> m||v||_1\le||v||_2\le M||v||_2
> $$
> for any $v\in V$.
>
> **Lemma**
>
> If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space then the function $||\cdot||_\infty:V\rightarrow\Bbb R^+_0$ defined through the condition
> $$
> ||v||_\infty:=\max_{i=1,...,n}|v_i|
> $$
> is a norm in $V$.
>
> **Theorem**
>
> If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space then all norm in $V$ are equivalent.

Clearly if $||\cdot||$ is a norm in $V$ then by triangle inequality
$$
||v||\le M\cdot||v||_\infty
$$
where $M:=\max_{i=1,...,n}||e_i||$ for any basis $\mathcal{B}:=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$.

Unfortunately I can't prove the other inequality. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: This question  has appeared many many times. Please try to search the site for it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Give me any second: I'm reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Method 1**

Suppose There are no $D>0$ s.t. for all $x\in V$, $\|x\|\geq D\|x\|_\infty $. This mean that
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N^*, \exists x_n\in V: \|x_n\|\leq \frac{\|x_n\|_\infty }{n}.$$

Instead of considering $y_n=\frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|_\infty }$, we can suppose WLOG that $\|x_n\|_\infty =1$ for all $n$. Therefore, by Bolzano-Weierstrass, there is a subsequence (still denoted $(x_n)$) that converges to $x$. Since a norm is continuous, you have $$\|x\|=\lim_{n\to \infty }\|x_n\|=0,$$
and thus $x=0$, but on the other hand, $$\|x\|_\infty =\lim_{n\to \infty }\|x_n\|_\infty =1,$$
which is a contradiction.

### **Method 2**

You have that $\|\cdot \|$ is continuous on $$S=\{x\in V\mid \|x\|_\infty =1\},$$ which is compact. Therefore, there are $x_0,x_1\in S$,  s.t. for all $x\in S$, $$0<\|x_0\|\leq \|x\|\leq \|x_1\|.$$
Since $$S=\left\{\frac{y}{\|y\|_\infty }\mid y\in V-\{0\}\right\},$$
you get the wished result.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understend why $\|x\|_\infty =\lim_{n\to \infty }\|x_n\|_\infty =1$; then whe without loos of generality we can suppose that $||x_n||=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$? Could you explain this to me, please?

Comment: because $\|x_n\|_\infty =1$ for all $n$. Therefore (and by continuity of $\|\cdot \|_\infty $) you get $\|x\|=\lim_{n\to \infty }\|x_n\|_\infty =1$.

Comment: Okay, and then why we can suppose without loss of generality that $||x_n||_\infty=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: Because we have $$\|x_n\|\leq \frac{1}{n}\|x_n\|_\infty \iff \left\|\frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|_\infty }\right\|\leq \frac{1}{n}.$$ Thus, either you set $y_n=\frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|_\infty }$ which is s.t. $\|y_n\|_\infty =1$, or you just suppose that $\|x_n\|_\infty =1$, and do the whole prove with $(x_n)$ instead of $y_n$ (what I did).

Comment: Okay, finally if we use Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem then the the subsequence $x_n$ is a subsequence of $y_n$, right? Forgive my confusion: unfortunately I'm confused by notation.

Comment: not at all. $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence for the supremum norm (because $\|x_n\|_\infty =1$). Therefore there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ that converges for $\|\cdot \|_\infty $. Instead of working with $(x_{n_k})$ I just supposed directly that $(x_n)$ converges (but you can rather work with $(x_{n_k})$ if this make thing more clear for you).

Comment: Okay, I understand: anyway I know that Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem is valid for the space $\Bbb R^n$ but I suppose that it can be generalise to metric spaces, right?

Comment: No, only normed vector space of finite dimension (because all normed space $(V,\|\cdot \|)$ of dimension $n$ is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot \|)$

Comment: Okay, thansk too much for your assistance!

Comment: Perhaps could you help me [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765387/a-generalization-of-bolzano-weierstrass-theorem-to-other-spaces)? It seems you know the proof of the general Bolzano-Weierstarss theorem.

Comment: However I'd like your second proof but I don't understand why the set $S$ is compact: could you explain this  to me?

Comment: $S$ is compact because it's closed, ($S=\|\cdot \|_\infty ^{-1}(\{1\})$ i.e. the converse image of a closed set by a continuous function) and obviously bounded (since $x\in S\implies \|x\|_\infty \leq1$). And in normed vector space of finite dimension, closed and bounded sets are compact (Heine-Borel-Theorem).

Comment: Okay. Clearly if $X$ is a normed space then any compact set $S$ is closed and bounded since $X$ is a metric space too. However if $S$ is closed and bounded how prove that it is compact? Is possible to do this without use the homeomorphism between $X$ and $\Bbb R^n$?